# 3 new Points lying on Jerabek Hyperbola?

Tags: geometry, triangles, conic-sections, triangle-centres

*R* is the circumcenter, *H* is the orthocenter of the triangle *ABC*.

Then points *F,G,E* are the points of intersection of the altitudes with the sides of the triangle ABC. *U, V, W* are the intersection points of cevians *AR, BR, CR* with the sides of the triangle *ABC*.

*X* is defined as the intersection of lines *GU*, *EF*. *Y* is defined as the intersection of *GU, WV* and *Z* is the intersection point of lines *WV, EF.*  Then it can be shown and proven that lines AX, BY, CZ always [intersect at the point *RH*.](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/cvgczahf)

**UPDATE**:  Actually, 4 '*RH*' points exist. **3 of them always belong to **[Jerabek hyperbola](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JerabekHyperbola.html)** that goes through A,B,C,R,H  and the fourth *RH* point lies on that hyperbola only in a special case.  All the points of this configuration are shown *[here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/gsxbm6hv)*.

I wonder what is known about these *RH* points, *K* points, *S* point and related conics?

In fact, **3 RH points can be any of those or completely new ones**:

*54 (Kosnita point), 64 isogonal conjugate of the de Longchamps point), 65 (orthocenter of the contact triangle), 66 (isogonal conjugate of the Exeter point), 67 (isogonal conjugate of the far-out point), 68 (Prasolov point), 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 248, 265, 290, 695, 879, 895, 1173, 1175, 1176, 1177, 1242, 1243, 1244, 1245, 1246, 1439, 1798, 1903, 1942, 1987, 2213, 2435, 2574, 2575, 2992, and 2993.*

Comment: You haven't defined $X$, $Y$, $Z$. In your GeoGebra sketch, it appears you want these to be vertices of a triangle determined by lines through appropriate pairs of points from the collection $F$, $G$, $E$, $U$, $V$, $W$ as discussed in your ["median bisector?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3748383/409) question. As noted in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3748904/409), there's some ambiguity involved, which in the current context leads to four possible definitions of your point $RH$. (I wonder if all four are on the hyperbola.) Point $L$ seems irrelevant to the discussion.

Comment: yes, the exact same principle as proposed there, is applied here as well. I used Geogebra's  [conic through 5 points] function and apparently the same hyperbola can be constructed for any set of 5 points (A,B,C, L,R),  (A,B,C, H, HR) (A,B,C, L,HR),  (B,C, H,R, HR) ....  etc.  so point L has indeed no special purpose here. (Besides the fact that it proves  that at least RH point is not point L.)

Comment: A quick *Mathematica* session seems to confirm that, in the notation of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3748904/409), points $K_A$, $K_B$, $K_C$ (corresponding to three possible interpretations of your $RH$ here) always lie on the conic through $A$, $B$, $C$ and defining points-of-concurrency $P_+$, $P_-$. The fourth possible pt, $K$, lies on the conic only if $$\left(
\frac{\alpha_+^2}{\alpha_-^2}-\frac{\beta_+^2}{\beta_-^2}
\right)\left(
\frac{\beta_+^2}{\beta_-^2}-\frac{\gamma_+^2}{\gamma_-^2}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma_+^2}{\gamma_-^2}-\frac{\alpha_+^2}{\alpha_-^2}\right)=0$$

Comment: In this particular case for the sake of simplicity X is defined as intersection of lines GU, EF.   Y is defined as intersection of GU, WV  and  Z  as intersection point of lines WV, EF.   Perhaps I should add a link to a Geogebra sketch, where all possible 4 points are constructed.

Comment: Comments are easily overlooked, so please include the explicit definition of $X$, $Y$, $Z$ in the body of your question. As noted in my comment(s) and answer(s), there's ambiguity here: It's not clear how/why you chose the specific pairs of cevian-points to get the lines that lead to $X$, $Y$, $Z$ (or $J$, $K$, $L$ in your previous question). There are ultimately four ways to go; *three* of those ways necessarily lead to a point $RH$ on the conic in question, which is great. However, *one* of them doesn't always work, so it's important that your description explain how you avoid that choice.

Comment: I constructed 3 'RH' points that lie on Jerabek hyperbole... RH, RH2, RH3. I also found that lines A RH(3), B RH(2), C RH intersect at another point that doesn't lie on a hyperbole. That can be the '4th RH point' or another one: geogebra.org/m/xfrwgdfm

Comment: I believe the fourth point you are describing is what I called "$K_\star$" in [my answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3748904/409). That point is not the same as the point (what I call "$K$") that arises from the fourth choice of pairings of cevian-points in your construction.

Comment: Now all 4 RH points can be finally shown. RH, RH2, RH3  lie on Jerabek hyperbola and RH4 does not. This construction also gives us 4 new conics: https://www.geogebra.org/m/gsxbm6hv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring back to [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3748904/409) to a related question, we'll consider things in a bit more generality, and handle an ambiguity in the formulation of this property.

Given $\triangle ABC$ we define points $P_+$ and $P_-$ (which correspond to the orthocenter and circumcenter in OP's current question) via barycentric coordinates
$$P_\pm = \frac{\alpha_\pm A+\beta_\pm B+\gamma_\pm C}{\alpha_\pm+\beta_\pm+\gamma_\pm} \tag{1}$$
Cevians through $P_+$ and $P_-$ meet the sides of the triangle in six points, $D_\pm$, $E_\pm$, $F_\pm$ (OP's $F$, $G$, $E$, $U$, $V$, $W$), and pairs of these points determine lines that meet pairwise at three more points, $D$, $E$, $F$ (OP's $X$, $Y$, $Z$). Finally, although there's ambiguity in choosing pairs of points that ultimately determine $D$, $E$, $F$, the cevians $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BE}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CF}$ always concur. As per my other answer, the points of concurrency (which I denote with sub-scripted (or not) $K$) have barycentric coordinates
$$\begin{align}
K_A  &= \left(\frac12:\frac{1}{\dfrac{\alpha_+}{\beta_+}+\dfrac{\alpha_-}{\beta_-}}:\frac{1}{\dfrac{\alpha_+}{\gamma_+}+\dfrac{\alpha_-}{\gamma_-}}\right) \tag2\\[4pt]
K_B &= \left(\frac{1}{\dfrac{\beta_+}{\alpha_+}+\dfrac{\beta_-}{\alpha_-}}:\frac12:\frac{1}{\dfrac{\beta_+}{\gamma_+}+\dfrac{\beta_-}{\gamma_-}}\right) \tag3 \\[4pt]
K_C &= \left(\frac{1}{\dfrac{\gamma_+}{\alpha_+}+\dfrac{\gamma_-}{\alpha_-}}:\frac{1}{\dfrac{\gamma_+}{\beta_+}+\dfrac{\gamma_-}{\beta_-}}:\frac12\right) \tag4 \\[4pt]
K\phantom{_X} &= \left(\frac1{\beta_+\gamma_- + \beta_-\gamma_+}:
\frac1{\gamma_+\alpha_-+\gamma_-\alpha_+}:\frac1{\alpha_+\beta_-+\alpha_- \beta_+}\right) \tag5
\end{align}$$
It's not clear which of these points OP intends by "$RH$", but $75\%$ of the time, it doesn't matter. :) To see why, note that the five-point conic through $A$, $B$, $C$, $P_+$, $P_-$ has barycentric equation

$$\frac{\alpha_+}{x} \left(\frac{\beta_+}{\beta_-} - \frac{\gamma_+}{\gamma_-}\right)
+ \frac{\beta_+}{y}\left( \frac{\gamma_+}{\gamma_-} - \frac{\alpha_+}{\alpha_-}\right)
+\frac{\gamma_+}{z}\left( \frac{\alpha_+}{\alpha_-} -\frac{\beta_+}{\beta_-}\right)= 0 \tag{6}$$
where $x:y:z$ are the barycentric coordinates of any point on the conic. The reader can verify that $K_A$, $K_B$, $K_C$ (one of which is what I *suspect* OP intends to be point "$RH$") automatically satisfy $(6)$, and that $K$ satisfies it only if
$$\left( \frac{\alpha_+}{\alpha_-}-\frac{\beta_+}{\beta_-} \right)\left( \frac{\beta_+}{\beta_-}-\frac{\gamma_+}{\gamma_-}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma_+}{\gamma_-}-\frac{\alpha_+}{\alpha_-}\right)=0 \tag{7}$$

(In a comment to the original question, I included squares in a formula corresponding to the above. My second pass at the problem seems to make the squares unnecessary. I'm going with that.)

Observe that if, say, the first factor of $(7)$ vanishes, equivalently, if $\alpha_+/\beta_+=\alpha_-/\beta_-$ then (via my previous answer) cevian points $F_+$ and $F_-$ coincide. Consequently we can interpret $(7)$ in general as the condition that $\overleftrightarrow{P_+P_-}$ passes through a vertex of $\triangle ABC$.

---

In OP's specific case using the circumcenter and orthocenter,
$$\begin{align}
R &= (\alpha_+:\beta_+:\gamma_+) = (\sin 2 A: \sin 2 B : \sin 2C ) \\
H &= (\alpha_-:\beta_-:\gamma_-) = (\tan A:\tan B:\tan C)
\end{align} \tag8$$
condition $(7)$ transforms to
$$(\cos^2A-\cos^2B)(\cos^2B-\cos^2C)(\cos^2C-\cos^2A)=0 \tag{9}$$
so that (non-degenerate) $\triangle ABC$ must be isosceles for the point $K$ to lie on the conic.

---

Regarding the "triangle center-ness" of these $K$-points, we can note that, even in general, $K_A$, $K_B$, $K_C$ are typically *not* triangle centers in the Kimberling sense, as they aren't *symmetrically-defined* by the parent triangle. As formulas $(2)$, $(3)$, $(4)$ show, the point you get depends upon how the vertices are labeled. (That's why the subscripts make sense!)

On the other hand, point $K$ (via $(5)$) *is* symmetrically-defined, and it therefore generally corresponds to a triangle center. In fact, it turns out that this point is known as the [Ceva Point](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cevapoint.html) for points $P_+$ and $P_-$. In particular, the Ceva Point for the orthocenter and circumcenter is designated $X(1105)$ in Kimberling's [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETCPart2.html).

The point where $\overleftrightarrow{AK_A}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BK_B}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CK_C}$ concur —which I call $K_\star$ in my previous answer— is also symmetrically-defined, so it counts as a "triangle center" of some kind. In fact, it is known as the [crosspoint](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Crosspoint.html) of $P_+$ and $P_-$. Its orthocenter-circumcenter incarnation is Kimberling's $X(185)$. (Interestingly, the ETC notes that this point is the orthocenter of the tangential triangle of the Jerabek hyperbola.)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, indeed, ,, points are 'too simple' and hardly can remain the 'undiscovered' ones. Point S looks like the ultimate 'target' of the whole construction. ,,,  points  and 4 ⋆ points are used mostly as the 'preparatory ones' for the construction of this point and it should be a symmetrically defined one. Lastly, if point K4 from my sketch is defined as X(185) in the ETC,  it appears that 3 remaining points ⋆ (K1,K2,K3) that are lying on the Euler line are not specified in the ETC. This collinearity is probably considered a bit too trivial again, though.

Comment: It's getting harder and harder to keep track of the alphabet soup of points in these constructions. :)  In any case, if you want to ask about this new point $S$, then you should post that as a separate question rather than continuing to increase the scope of this one. If/when you do so, make sure your question is as self-contained as possible, with all points clearly defined. (You can, of course, link back to this question and the previous one for context.) Please also provide *images* of your construction; people shouldn't have to visit an external site to understand what you're describing.

Comment: I doubled checked everything, and I can assure you that point S clearly exists ;) There won't be any future edits in this construction: https://www.geogebra.org/m/gsxbm6hv  I also 'codified and simplified' the names of all the points. (Too bad,  that  'S Point'  is probably already well-defined in the ETC and it might not worth the efforts to explore it, especially if crosspoints and Ceva-Points are used by geometers.)  With that said I keep in mind everything you post and truly appreciate everything you do! It might be a better idea to come up with a new question in a month or two.